# Why there is no normal force acting on the book?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

[image]

Why no normal force is shown in this diagram??

Comment: please give a link/reference for this. it needs clarity.

Comment: When I hold a book on my hands so there will be a muscular force which will counteracts the weight of the book. But where is the normal force between my hands and book since they are in contact

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think gandalf61 is right - this seems to be a diagram of the forces acting on the arm (only the arm is considered the "body", or the "system"); the book is being ignored (except as something that weighs down on the arm), as it is not the body of interest in this particular case. The misleading thing is that $\textbf w_b$ is shown, but that's not what's actually acting on the arm. Think through the action-reaction pairs for *all* the forces acting on the book.

Comment: If I assume my hands and block as a system so then normal force between my hand and book will be internal forces and there is no need to show them as I think

Comment: Then the only external force left will be muscular force and gravitational force

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clue is in the words "Free-body diagram". This diagram only shows the internal and external forces that are acting on the arm. The external forces are the book's weight $w_b$ and the arm's weight $w_a$. The internal forces are $F_B$ and $F_E$. The normal force exerted by the arm on the book is not shown because this acts on the book, not on the arm.

(Note that technically $w_b$ is a normal force - it is the normal exerted by the book on the arm - but this is equal in magnitude and direction to the book's weight).

Answer (score 1):

You are right to assume that for the book to remain stationary in the palm of the person, an equal and opposite (normal) force should act on the book to counter the downward pull. In my opinion, the diagram assumes that ultimately the source of this force comes from the biceps exerting an upward force $F_B$, and as such it only labels that force.

Note: You would need to provide more text to get a clearer answer.